# Apache Cassandra remote access

Tags: cassandra, remote-access

I have installed Apache Cassandra on the remote Ubuntu server. How to allow remote access for an Apache Cassandra database? And how to make a connection?

Answer (score 47):

Remote access to Cassandra is via its thrift port (although note that the JMX port can be used to perform some limited operations).

The thrift port is defined in `cassandra.yaml` by the `rpc_port` parameter, which defaults to 9160. Your cassandra node should be bound to the IP address of your server's network card - it shouldn't be `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` which is the loopback interface's IP, binding to this will prevent direct remote access. You configure the bound address with the `rpc_address` parameter in cassandra.yaml. Setting this to `0.0.0.0` says "listen on all network interfaces" which may or may not be suitable for you.

To make a connection you can use:

- The cassandra-cli in the cassandra distribution's bin directory provides simple get / set / list operations and depends on Java
- The cqlsh shell which provides CQL access to cassandra, this depends on Python
- A higher level interface such as [Apollo](http://www.codefreun.de/en/apollo-en)

Comment: Can you run these commands:

    ps -ef | grep CassandraDaemon ;
    netstat -lntp | grep <pid from above command>

This will show what IP / port combo(s) your cassandra is listening on.

As an aside, try to avoid telneting to the thrift port - passing in any non thrift data can lead to OutOfMemory situations (it's quite a nasty 'feature' - to test & confirm this, telnet to the thrift port type in random text, hit return, then monitor memory usage of the CassandraDaemon pid over the next few mins).

Comment: Note that Cassandra is robust to random garbage on the Thrift port since version 0.7.0 two years ago.

Comment: Ahh ok, yeah you're right - i just tried there on a v1.1-0 instance (while [1]; do nc 127.0.0.1 9168 < /mach_kernel; done) even after 2Gb of binary data, heap usage doesn't go above 240Mb for me. I feel a bit daft now for having been perpetuating a falsehood! I live and learn :-) (p.s. great product Mr Bellis)

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57621           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8536/java       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8536/java       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7199            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8536/java       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:47684           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8536/java       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9160          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8536/java

Comment: My output looks like this. Seems like it's listening only localhost on port 9160, although i configured rpc_address to 0.0.0.0 What's wrong?

Comment: Interesting. I guess we should check the basics first: Cassandra has been restarted since applying the change? The correct Cassandra.yaml was updated? Can you confirm nothing is already listening on 9160 on the network cards ip address (netstat -an | grep 9160) - just to be doubly sure that port is available can you run (nc -l -p 9160 -v)

Comment: i have running Cassandra cluster, In that i can able to connect Cluster from some of my network System, but i am not able to connect from my system. Even while running scala class with same cluster configuration connect successfully. but while running project it give message like  does nor able to open native connection to cassandra for any of cluster node.  Spark version 1.5.2, Scala version : 2.11.7 Cassandra Version 3.6, Spark Cassandra Connector version 1.5.0-RC1        i am stuck on it, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone finding this question now, the top answer is out of date.

Apache Cassandra's thrift interface is deprecated and will be removed in Cassandra 4.0. The default client port is now 9042.

As noted by Tyler Hobbs, you will need to ensure that the [rpc_address](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/configuration/cassandra_config_file.html#rpc-address) parameter is not set to 127.0.0.1 or localhost (it is localhost by default). If you set it to `0.0.0.0` to listen on all interfaces, you will also need to set [broadcast_rpc_address](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/configuration/cassandra_config_file.html#broadcast-rpc-address) to either the node's public or private IP address (depending on how you plan to connect to Cassandra)

Cassandra-cli is also deprecated and Apollo is no longer active. Use [cqlsh](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/cqlsh.html) in lieu of cassandra-cli and the [Java driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) in lieu of Apollo.

I do not recommend making the JMX port accessible remotely unless you [secure it properly](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/security.html#jmx-access) by enabling SSL and strong authentication.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I tried many solution for cassandra version 3.11.2, none of them worked for me,

Answer (score 6):

> cassandra 3.11.3

I did the following to get mine working. Changes in cassandra.yaml :

```
start_rpc: true

rpc_address: 0.0.0.0

broadcast_rpc_address: ***.***.***.***
```

broadcast_rpc_address is the address of machine where cassandra is installed

```
 seed_provider:
  - class_name: ...
    - seeds: "127.0.0.1, ***.***.***.***"
```

In seeds i added/appended the ip address of machine where cassandra was running.

I accessed it from windows using [tableplus](https://tableplus.io/). In tableplus, I wrote the ip address of the cassandra machine, in the port section I wrote `9042` and used the username and password, which i used for ssh connection.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using Azure, the issue may be that you need to create a public ip address since the virtual ip points to the cloud service itself and not the virtual machine. You can find more info [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976998/how-to-connect-to-cassandra-remotely-using-devcenter/29993081#29993081)