# spark connection to cassandra, fail op open connection

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

This is my build.sbt

```
name := "cassandra_test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.databricks" %% "spark-avro" % "2.0.1",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.0",
"com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.5.0")
```

and I have installed Cassandra 3.2 (EDIT: now using 2.1.12), the contents of the yaml are, I believe, the correct ones from what I have gathered:

```
rpc_address: 127.0.0.1 (EDIT: now 0.0.0.0)
rpc_port: 9160
start_rpc: true
broadcast_rpc_address: 127.0.0.1
```

I am able to start sessions via `cqlsh` , create tables, query and such.

However, when I try to use the spark connection, I always get:

```
 java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {127.0.0.1}:9160
```

these are the contents of my scala code

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

object cassandra_test{

  def main(args: Array[String]){

    val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1").set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9160")
    val sc = new SparkContext("local", "Cassandra Connector Test", conf)
    val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test", "kv")
    println(rdd.count)
   }
}
```

I've looked around for answers but I think I've covered all the possibilities that I've seen. I have also tried to replace the localhost IP address for the actual IP address. Doing that I can connect via cqlsh but not via spark.

Also tried replacing "127.0.0.1" with "localhost" when setting up `conf`, but to no avail.

The cassandra connector seems to be the right version too, according to the [github](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) page.

No more ideas of what to try unfortunately!

What could be wrong?

**=====================================================**

EDIT: So I finally solved this. First, I compiled the connector library locally so that I could link it as a jar file and open it with:

```
spark-shell --jars /mnt/spark-cassandra-connector/spark-cassandra-connector/target/scala-2.10/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.6.0-M1-12-gc37bb3c.jar --master local
```

Note the `--master local`. That was the important piece that was missing. Then I would run on the shell:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql

sc.stop
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","localhost")
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test", "kv")
println(rdd.count)
```

Which would always fail without the **--master local** part on the shell command.

On the scala code, this means that changing the definition of `conf` to:

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost").setMaster("local")
```

did the trick too.

I still **don't really understand** what is going on, if anybody cares to explain, that would be awesome.

Comment: Can you try with `local[*]` instead of `local` master?

Comment: you meant this right? ` val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "Cassandra Connector Test", conf)` Unfortunately I get the same error :(

Comment: Maybe try 0.0.0.0 as RPC address, and restart Cassandra

Comment: It refuses to launch with that setting :( Apparently you can set it to anything *other* than 0.0.0.0

Comment: How so? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12240400/1395437

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. What is actually not possible is to have the `broadcast_rpc_address` to 0.0.0.0. By default, the `broadcast_rpc_address` is set to whatever `rpc_address` is. So if one changes `rpc_adress` to 0.0.0.0 you need to change `broadcast_rpc_adress` to something *other* than 0.0.0.0

Comment: the error still persists by the way :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between your working and non-working code is using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` for the key `spark.cassandra.connection.host`, this should be the root cause of your problem.

A somewhat unrelated tip: You can launch the `spark-shell` with the flag `--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.0-M1` to avoid compiling the jar yourself.

Comment: are you sure, because I tried that several times and it never worked until I tried that.

Comment: Well you clearly set the master to local in the first example too, so that can't be it.

Answer (score 1):

The Spark Cassandra connector does not support Cassandra 3.2. You should use a lower version, see the version compatibility sheet in the readme of their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector).

Comment: oh I see, I misread that chart then. I'll reinstall and re-try in a little while and accept your answer, thanks.

Comment: I would also use the 1.5 version of the connector. Not sure what the status is on 1.6.0-M1

Comment: Did all the changes and still no luck. I'm using Cassandra 2.2 with Spark 1.6 and the 1.5 connector. Very frustrating!

Comment: yep, no problems `Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9160.
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.1.12 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]`

Comment: Can you copy the entire stack trace into your question?

Comment: Hey, that was helpful actually, see my edit. Would you happen to know what has happening and why the fix works? Feel free to explain via an answer instead of a comment so that I can accept.

Comment: In theory I think spark connector 1.5+ will work with any cassandra 3.X version as there aren't any protocol level changes between 3.0 and 3.2.